# Mapping that takes unit circle to unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A \subset \mathbb{C} $ be an open set containing the closed unit disc.
Let $f$ be an analytic function from $A$ to $\mathbb{C}$ such that $|f(z)|=1$ if $|z|=1$.

Does it follow that $f(z) = a z^{n} \frac{cz^{m}-b}{1-cz^{m}\bar{b}} $ for some $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $|c|=1$ $|a|=1$, $|b|<1$ and some $n,m\ge 0 $?

Comment: What about $z\mapsto(z^n-b)/(1-\overline b z^n)$?

Comment: Thanks Robin.   I changed my question in response

Comment: You define two sets of functions and ask if they coincide. The first set is closed under multiplication and composition. You should check that the second set has the same property.

Comment: @Moron - f is not supposed to be entire.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, as there is no reason to suppose the function entire. But the OP should look at Blaschke products.

Comment: OH. I missed that in this question. Sorry, agree it is not a dupe.

Comment: @Chandru1 - http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/787/single-comment-split-into-many-comments

Comment: Robin thanks for the hint on Blaschke products. This answers my question

Comment: If $0<d<1$, then $(z-d)^2/(1-dz)^2$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting part of my answer to [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3408/characterizing-non-constant-entire-functions-with-modulus-1-on-the-unit-circle) is my answer to yours (and Robin basically already said it in the comments):

> If a function $f$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of the closed disk and has modulus 1 on the circle, then $f$ is a [finite Blaschke product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product#Finite_Blaschke_products).  You can prove this by taking all of the zeros inside the disk counted according to multiplicity, dividing by corresponding [holomorphic automorphisms of the disk](https://planetmath.org/AutomorphismsOfUnitDisk) that have those zeros, and showing that the result is constant.  (This quotient and its reciprocal are analytic and bounded by 1 on the disk...)

Of course I'm assuming $A$ is connected.

Comment: Community wiki because I'm just copying my other answer, and because the answer was already given in the comments.  But I thought this question might as well have an "Answer".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is No. Recall the question:

Let $A\subset\mathbb{C}$ be an open set containing the closed unit disc. Let $f$ be an analytic function from $A$ to $\mathbb{C}$ such that $|f(z)|=1$ if $|z|=1$.

Does it follow that 
$$f(z)=az^{n}\,\frac{cz^{m}-b}{1-\bar{b}cz^{m}}$$ 
for some $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $|c|=1$, $|a|=1$, $|b|\le1$ and some $n,m\ge0$?

Let $B$ be the set of analytic functions from $A$ to $\mathbb{C}$ such that $|f(z)|=1$ if $|z|=1$, and let $C$ the set of rational fractions of the indicated form.

If $f$ is an element of $C$ with $0<|b|<1$ and $m\ge1$, then $z\mapsto f(z)^2$ is in $B$, but, having a multiple zero $z_0\not=0$, is not in $C$.