# Find all $f$ such that $\vert f(z) \vert = \vert e^z \vert$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $B_1(0)$ and continuous on $\overline{B_1(0)}$. Assume

$$\vert f(z) \vert = \vert e^z \vert$$

for all $z \in \partial B_1(0)$. Find all such $f$. Isn't this just going to be

$$f(n)=e^{\pi i n}$$

for every integer $n$. Or can I take

$$f_n(z):=\frac{n}{n+1}e^z?$$

Comment: Are you claiming that $|e^z| = 1$ whenever $|z| = 1$?

Comment: "Is the above equality equal to just $1$"? What does this mean

Comment: What are you trying to deduce about the function anyway?

Comment: @FShrike I thought that $\vert e^z \vert = 1$ on the unit circle? Im trying to find all such $f$ that have same modulus as $e^z$.

Comment: $z=1$ is on the unit circle but $|e^1|=e\gt1$. Rethink...

Comment: Aha good catch guys. I thought so too.

Comment: No, $|e^z| = 1$ on the line $\text{Re}(z)=0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks, brain fart there for a moment.

Comment: $f(n)$ isn't defined for $n>2$ since $f$ is defined on $B(0,1)$

Comment: @Didier aha good catch!

Comment: @Didier wait, are you referring to my $f(n)$ or my $f_n(z)$?

Comment: What is $f(n)$ ? Aren't you looking for all functions that satisfy the inequality? Surely there are such functions which are defined at more than just integer values?

Comment: @Carlyle take a look at my $f_n(z)$.

Comment: When $z = 1 + 0i$, $|e^z| = e$, but $f_1(1 + 0i) = \frac{e}{2} + 0i$ so $|f_1(z)| = \frac{e}{2} \neq e$ isn't it?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame: You are on the wrong track. *Hint:*  Consider $g(z) = e^{-z} f(z)$. What can you say about $g$ on $\partial B_1(0)$? What can you conclude?

Comment: @MartinR its modulus is bounded by $1$? on the boundary.

Comment: @FShrike: No, not constant.

Comment: @MartinR No? What’s my flaw

Comment: @FShrike: What about $g(z) = z^7$? Or $g(z) = (z-2)/(1-2z)$? Look up “Blaschke factor”.

Comment: @MartinR Excuse me, I misread the original post. I was thinking that $|f(z)|=|e^z|$ for all $z$, not just $z$ on the boundary

Comment: Can we actually determine anything about $g$, from its having constant modulus on the circle? @MartinR I'm really curious what the strategy is

Comment: Yes, @MartinR so am I

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54386/42969 for a full characterization.