# Entire function constant on $|z|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is entire function such that $|f(z)|=1$ on $C(0,1)$. Show that $f(z)=k z^n$ for some constant $k$,$|k|=1$, and for some nonnegative integer $n$.

I was thinking to apply Blaschke product by breaking the number of zeros of $f(z)$ inside the circle and outside the circle. I also have to consider the cases $f(z)$ might have infinitely many zero in the whole complex plane or it might never vanish. I am getting confuse how to start.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A detailed answer can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3408/characterizing-nonconstant-entire-functions-with-modulus-1-on-the-unit-circle

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{\overline{f(1/\overline{z})}}$ on the circle, and therefore...

Comment: I guess it is same function again ,right?

Comment: I did not see what you are trying to say.

Comment: Therefore the only possible zero is at $z=0$.  Also, after dividing by $z^n$ where $n$ is the order of that zero (if any), you get a bounded entire function.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help.