# Suppose $f(z)$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb C$, and there are two circles $K, K'$, so that $f(K)⊂K'$, prove that $f(z)$ is a rational function.

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

Suppose $f(z)$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb C$, and there are two circles $K$, $K'$, so that $f(K)⊂K'$, prove that $f(z)$ is a rational function.

I think $f(z)$ has to extend to $\mathbb{C}∪\{∞\}$ and then uses Liouvile's theorem. But how to prove that $f(z)$ can extend to $\mathbb{C}∪\{∞\}$, by polynomial function?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Sketch of how to go about it - use Mobius transforms to send both circles to the unit circle and compose appropriately so we can assume wlog $|f(z)|=1$ when $|z|=1$; show that this implies that $f$ must be analytic either inside or outside the unit disc (this is essentially topological stuff plus open mapping theorem for nonconstant meromorphic functions)  and then if $f$ analytic outside use $f(1/z)$ so assume $f$ analytic inside and then extracting the finite zeroes inside the unit disc show $f$ is a finite Blaschke product hence rational

Comment: This question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3408/42969 is about entire functions, but this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3436/42969  applies  to meromorphic functions as well: *“If a function $f$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of the closed disk and has modulus $1$ on the circle, then $f$ is a finite Blaschke product.”* – Therefore I would suggest to close this as a duplicate.